# Is there performance penalty for div tree depth?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there performance difference between:

```
    <div>
      <a> ... </a>
    </div>
```

and:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <a> ... </a>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

For Browsers I think it doesn't make sense but in my case I have list of 200 items that run on mobile.

So I pretty sensitive to performance.

Thanks,

Comment: any particular reason you need to have a deep dom?

Comment: Yes, but it's negligible. CSS abd JavaScript are usually your major issues, not HTML.

Comment: @Populus generally ,yes, In angular I use directive defined as elements that must be wrapped by root DOM element. it demands me to add additional `div`

Comment: The answer to "does dom complexity affect performance?" is almost certainly yes, though to what extent depends on how --awful-- nested/none-semantic the html is. Since I have no references, no answer.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to do paging if you feel there are too many items...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are some potential performance issues. You should consider:

- Download time. More HTML means a larger file, which takes longer to download.
- DOM size. More elements means that the page uses more memory.
- Rendering time. More elements means that the page is drawn more slowly.

What you would notice most is normally the download time. If the page is still reasonbly small you should be ok. If you are creating a lot of elements dynamically, then the other two could be noticable without the loading time being the problem.

As few as 200 items shouldn't be a big problem though.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of mobile, the more nested the DOM tree is, more chances for performance issues.

When the DOM tree becomes nested too much, traversing through the DOM tree will be PITA. It's always better to maintain flat DOM tree.

Even styling gets difficult when the DOM gets nested a lot.

In terms of page load speed, lesser the content more will be the page speed. If you are going to nest too many content in same page, it's going to affect the loading of page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should optimize that using section as below :

```
<section> </section> => for your content
```

But, why using 3 divs with no id and class ?

You should reduce your DOM like that :

```
<div> <a href="/yourlink" title="Your title" target="_blank" rel="Your title">Content</a>   </div>
```

More you should reduce your DOM loading content in order to improve load , don't use three divs if you have no class and id on it :)

Comment: I don't know where you got your information from, but `rel` does not mean anything to the blind.